# Ionic AppFlow builds in development instead of production mode

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-appflow

I'm using the Ionic AppFlow Live Update deployment feature without problems but the build is made using the **development** environment instead of production. I have a similar app using Live Update that builds correctly in production environment and I can't find any differences in the configuration of both apps.

I have two environment files:

```
environment.prod.ts
environment.ts
```

and the app is using the `environment.ts` configuration, which is for development.

I can install correctly the app in production mode in a device through USB using:

```
$ ionic cap copy --configuration=production
$ ionic cap open android
```

How can I **force AppFlow to use the production environment** for the build?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.3.2",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
...
}
```

ionic.config.json

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "angular"
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "baseHref": "/",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": ["src/theme/variables.scss", "src/global.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
    ]
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that because I'm using the free AppFlow version there is no Environments option. So I changed the build script to:

```
"build": "ng build --configuration=production",
```

and it worked.

In the Basic Plan and above, you can create environments and environments variables, as described in the [official documentation](https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/quickstart/environment).